# SQL Calculation of Row on All Rows of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am computing a similarity score for baseball players.  What I am trying to do is select a row based on a playerID, and then preform a calculation on all other existing players.

This is the general concept:

[image: Tables to Score]

I've written code that works for a single playerID compared to another playerID:

```
SELECT p.player, pc.player, 
     1000 - (Abs((p.G-pc.G)/20) + 
     Abs((p.AB-pc.AB)/75) + 
     Abs((p.R-pc.R)/10) +
     Abs((p.H-pc.H)/15) +
     Abs((p.D-pc.D)/5) +
     Abs((p.T-pc.T)/4) +
     Abs((p.HR-pc.HR)/2) +
     Abs((p.RBI-pc.RBI)/10) +
     Abs((p.BB-pc.BB)/25) +
     Abs((p.SO-pc.SO)/150) +
     Abs((p.SB-pc.SB)/20) +
     Abs((p.AVG-pc.AVG)*1000) +
     Abs((p.SLG-pc.SLG)*2000)) AS SIMscore

FROM(SELECT CONCAT(m.nameFirst, ' ', m.nameLast) AS player, 
     Sum(b.G) AS G, 
     Sum(b.AB) AS AB, 
     Sum(b.R) AS R, 
     Sum(b.H) AS H,
     Sum(b.2b) AS D, 
     Sum(b.3b) AS T, 
     Sum(b.HR) AS HR, 
     Sum(b.RBI) AS RBI, 
     Sum(b.BB) AS BB,     
     Sum(b.SO) AS SO, b.SB AS SB, 
     Sum(b.H)/Sum(b.AB) AS AVG,
     (Sum(b.H)+Sum(b.2b)*2+Sum(b.3B)*3+Sum(b.HR)*4)/Sum(b.AB) AS SLG
  FROM Batting b
  JOIN Master m
  ON b.playerID = m.playerID
  WHERE b.playerID = 'griffke02') AS p,
  (SELECT CONCAT(m.nameFirst, ' ', m.nameLast) AS player, 
      Sum(b.G) AS G, 
      Sum(b.AB) AS AB, 
      Sum(b.R) AS R, 
      Sum(b.H) AS H,
      Sum(b.2b) AS D, 
      Sum(b.3b) AS T, 
      Sum(b.HR) AS HR, 
      Sum(b.RBI) AS RBI, 
      Sum(b.BB) AS BB, 
      Sum(b.SO) AS SO, 
      Sum(b.SB) AS SB, 
      Sum(b.H)/Sum(b.AB) AS AVG,
      (Sum(b.H)+Sum(b.2b)*2+Sum(b.3B)*3+Sum(b.HR)*4)/Sum(b.AB) AS SLG
  FROM Batting b
  JOIN Master m
  ON b.playerID = m.playerID
  WHERE b.playerID = 'troutmi01') AS pc
```

But, I need it to compare the single playerID to all other players rather than just `WHERE b.playerID = 'troutmi01'`

```
SELECT CONCAT(m.nameFirst, ' ', m.nameLast) AS player, 
      Sum(b.G) AS G, 
      Sum(b.AB) AS AB, 
      Sum(b.R) AS R, 
      Sum(b.H) AS H,
      Sum(b.2b) AS D, 
      Sum(b.3b) AS T, 
      Sum(b.HR) AS HR, 
      Sum(b.RBI) AS RBI, 
      Sum(b.BB) AS BB, 
      Sum(b.SO) AS SO, 
      Sum(b.SB) AS SB, 
      Sum(b.H)/Sum(b.AB) AS AVG,
      (Sum(b.H)+Sum(b.2b)*2+Sum(b.3B)*3+Sum(b.HR)*4)/Sum(b.AB) AS SLG
  FROM Batting b
  JOIN Master m
  ON b.playerID = m.playerID
```

Any insight?

Comment: add `group by CONCAT(m.nameFirst, ' ', m.nameLast)` mysql is using the [group by extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) and rolling them all up and randomly choosing what concat (player) to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(m.nameFirst, ' ', m.nameLast) AS player, 
      Sum(b.G) AS G, 
      Sum(b.AB) AS AB, 
      Sum(b.R) AS R, 
      Sum(b.H) AS H,
      Sum(b.2b) AS D, 
      Sum(b.3b) AS T, 
      Sum(b.HR) AS HR, 
      Sum(b.RBI) AS RBI, 
      Sum(b.BB) AS BB, 
      Sum(b.SO) AS SO, 
      Sum(b.SB) AS SB, 
      Sum(b.H)/Sum(b.AB) AS AVG,
      (Sum(b.H)+Sum(b.2b)*2+Sum(b.3B)*3+Sum(b.HR)*4)/Sum(b.AB) AS SLG
  FROM Batting b
  JOIN Master m
  ON b.playerID = m.playerID
GROUP BY CONCAT(m.nameFirst, ' ', m.nameLast)
```

Add a group by...

As to why you need to understand [Mysql Group By Extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Specifically:
"However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. "

They are not the same in your case.  Player will be different each record, thus the need to add it to the group by.

Comment: Thank you, xQbert. Your solution worked perfectly. I will certainly reread on the group by functionality to understand more.  Much appreciated